# Delete data on Laravel application should have restrict behavior but it doesn't

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I have these two tables created from migrations in my application:

```
Schema::create('sectors', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
}

Schema::create('functions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->foreign('sector_id')->references('id')->on('sectors')->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('cascade');
}
```

So, when I delete some 'sector' row, the delete is successfull, but wasn't I supposed to get an MySQL error #1451 since the onDelete action is setted as `RESTRICT`? And the same happens when I delete data directly from database, via phpMyAdmin. What is wrong?

Comment: Are you deleting sectors or functions?

Comment: I had mistyped it. Already edited, srry

Answer (score 0):

No, quite the opposite when you delete a `'sector'` row that is related (as `'sector_id'`) to some `'function(s)'` record(s), you should get the `MySQL` error #1451 since the onDelete action is set as RESTRICT

[For more details](https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/on-delete-restrict-vs-on-delete-no-action/)

Comment: did you checked if deleted 'sector' rows IDs are used somewhere ? if NO you will not  get the MySQL error #1451